# Ionic cordova build ios - cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

Getting below error

cannot read property 'name' of undefined

while building ionic app in mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
modify platform/ios/cordova/lib/list-emulator-build-targets:

change:
if (device.name === deviceType.name.replace(/\-inch/g, ' inch') && 
   device.availability.toLowerCase().indexOf('unavailable') < 0) {
   availAcc.push(device);
}

to:

if (device.name === deviceType.name.replace(/\-inch/g, ' inch')) {
                        if ((device.availability && device.availability.toLowerCase().indexOf('unavailable') < 0)
                        || device.isAvailable) {
                            availAcc.push(device);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Please edit your questions with more context, please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask